# Exporting attributes of multiple shapefiles to a text file

Tags: python, text, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to export the attributes of multiple shapefiles all contained in one folder to a text file. I wrote the code below to do so but it is only exporting the file names to a text file. Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong? I've been troubleshooting and researching for a while.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\user\\rainfiles"
table = "C:\\user\\rain_files"
outWorkspace = "C:\\user"
fclist = arcpy.ListFields(table)
field_names = [field.name for field in fclist] 
for field in fclist:
    with open(r'C:\\user\\Exports.txt', 'w') as f:
        for field in fclist:
            f.write(field + '\n')
with open(r'C:\\user\\Exports.txt', 'r') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f) 
    w.writerow(field_names)            
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(table):  
        field_vals = [row.getValue(field.name) for field in fclist]  
        w.writerow(field_vals)
    del row
```

Comment: What is C:\user\rain_files? Is that the directory full of shapefiles? If so, ListFields is not a valid thing to do to it. ListFields should be called on a feature class, such as a shapefile. See http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfields.htm

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add an example of what you hope to see as output? I'm very confused, especially by the call to `ListFields` and the `for field in fclist` loop inside another `for field in fclist` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
import arcpy
import csv

f = open(r'C:\\user\\Exports.txt', 'w')
w = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\user\\rainfiles"

shapefileList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")
for table in shapefileList:
    f.write("Shapefile:\n")
    f.write(table + "\n")
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(table)
    field_names = [field.name for field in fieldList]
    w.writerow(field_names)
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(table):
        field_vals = []
        for field in fieldList:
            val = row.getValue(field.name)
            # See if it's a geometry field; if so, use WKT
            try:
                val = val.WKT
            except AttributeError:
                # It's not a geometry, and that's okay
                pass
            field_vals.append(val)
        w.writerow(field_vals)
```